# Vue 3 upload image input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have some unusual problems with Vue 3 and uploading image.
I have updated my app from Vue 3 beta to Vue 3 stable with Vite, and normally there was a lot of problems but I fixed most of it, but there is this one that I cannot understand really.
The image upload worked just fine, but now it's only returning a name of the file, but not the file and it's not recognizing it as an image/file.

Here is the code of the component:

```
<template>
  <div class="field">
    <div class="file is-boxed  has-name" :class="{'is-success': value, 'is-danger': !!errorMessage}">
      <label class="file-label">
        <input
          class="file-input"
          type="file"
          :name="name"
          @blur="handleBlur"
          @reset="handleReset"
          @input="onFieldChange"
          autocomplete="off"
        >

        <div class="file-cta">
          <span class="file-icon"> <i class="fas fa-upload"></i> </span>
          <span class="file-label">{{fileLabel}}</span>
        </div>

        <span class="file-name"> {{value ?? 'Please select a file!' }} </span>
      </label>
    </div>

    <ErrorMessage :name="name" class="help is-danger is-black" as="div" />

  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {ref} from "vue";
import {useField,  ErrorMessage} from "vee-validate";

export default {
  components: {
    ErrorMessage
  },
  name: "BaseFileField",
  emits: ['onChange', 'update:modelValue'],
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    fileLabel: {
      type: [String],
      required: true
    },
    modelValue: {
      required: true
    }
  },
  setup(props: any, {emit}: any) {

    //Import all the needed dependencies from the vee-validate
    const {
      handleBlur, handleReset, handleChange, value, meta, errorMessage, errors
    } = useField(props.name, undefined, {
      initialValue : props.modelValue,
    });

    return  {
      errorMessage, handleReset,  handleBlur, value,  meta,  errors,
      onFieldChange: (e: any ) => {
        const selectedFile = e.target.files[0].name;
        handleChange(selectedFile);
        emit("update:modelValue", e.target.files[0]);
        emit('onChange', e);
      },
    }

  }
}
</script>
```

And that's how I use it in other components

```
<BaseS3UploadField name="partnerLogo[en]" file-label="Upload a logo" v-model="selectedTranslations.en.logo"/>
```

And after I pass it to the function to upload on server, I'm checking like:

```
if (payload.logo instanceof File) {
      fd.append('logo', payload.logo)
    }
```

It's shown in the payload but as an empty object. Not as a binary, but it still recognizes it as an instance of a File.

Why it is sending an empty object? :/

Comment: _"Why it is not receiving a file?"_... what is _it_? All you've shown above is a component that emits events. Where are you listening to those?

Comment: That doesn't show anything 

Comment: @Phil maybe that would be enough?

Comment: FormData can not send Objects - it only sends `text` and `binary` content. Can you show the captured HTTP request from the browser to the server?